# Date column messes up when using ts() function

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I used the `lubridate` package in order to convert the date column from character to Date format. Then I wanted to create a Time-Series using of the `ts()` function which results the date column being a random 5-digit number instead.

How did that happen and how can I remedy this issue?

My data is in the following structure (illustrative):

```
Date    Food_inflation.   Energy Inflation
2001-01 2.5               3.0
2001-02 2.1               2.3
```